BPF_KSYSCALL use in eBPF program is asking for identifier on the first argument
This is a follow-up question to this question.
I have an eBPF program I am trying to make to hook into a read system call. I know I want to use the BPF_KSYSCALL macro from libbpf's 'bpf_tracing.h' header file to help read in the arguments of the system call, but I don't understand how to correctly use it to create a function signature.
I have what follows with 'entry_read' as the name argument
int BPF_KSYSCALL(entry_read, int fd, char* buf, int count) {
but I get an error saying 'expected identifier'. I have tried adding a 'char*' as the type of the name to make the following...
int BPF_KSYSCALL(char* entry_read, int fd, char* buf, int count) {
but I thought that wasn't correct because the name argument represents the name of the program that would be used. How far off am I?
Here is my full eBPF program for reproducing the problem:
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

struct data_args_t {
    int fd;
    const char* buf;
};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, __u64);
    __uint(max_entries, 100);
} active_read_args_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("kprobe/sys_read")
int BPF_KSYSCALL(entry_read, int fd, char* buf, int count) {
    int id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    struct data_args_t read_args = {};

    read_args.fd = fd;
    read_args.buf = buf;
    bpf_map_update_elem(&active_read_args_map, &id, &read_args, BPF_NOEXIST);

    return 0;
}

char __license[] SEC("license") = "Dual MIT/GPL";

UPDATE:
I'm including some of the background here so that you don't have to read an entire other post for the details.
I am on kernel version: 5.15.0-119-generic and I'm using libbpf-dev version: 1:0.5.0-1ubuntu22.04.1
I am compiling the code with ebpf-go's ebpf2go function
I've also included the gen.go file below used with ebpf2go.
package main

//go:generate go run github.com/cilium/ebpf/cmd/bpf2go logger logger.c

This is pulled from the ebpf-go 'getting started' tutorial.

Please provide a [mre].

Your section (SEC) is incorrect. It should be as follows:
SEC("ksyscall/read")
int BPF_KSYSCALL(entry_read, int fd, char* buf, int count) {
    ...
}

With that, I'm able to compile, load, and attach the BPF program as expected.

I changed the SEC to match what you have above, but I'm still getting the "expected identifier" error

Then there's some other issue outside of the BPF program because I'm able to load that BPF program. Is your program exactly as posted? What version of libbpf are you using? How are you loading the program? On what kernel?

I've updated the question with those details. The only thing I can think of that I didn't include was the gen.go file that I've added to the above post and the main.go file but I hit this error before I even try to build & run that file.
